# Fix Hugo Academic / Markdown Date - It's always Jan 1, 0001

Tags: markdown, hugo

For anything marked 'post' on my site, the date, no matter the format I input it, comes out as Jan, 1 0001. Here is what I have tried for my top matter:

```
---
  title: Assessing Your Carbon Footprint from Google Location Data
author: 'name'
date: "2020-02-10"
---
```

I've also tried `2020-02-10T00:00:00Z`.
The date works on other page types (e.g. project, talk, publication).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened but the following fixed it:

```
---
title: "Assessing Your Carbon Footprint with Google Location Data"
author: "name"
date: '2020-02-10'
```

Maybe the title not being wrapped in quotes?

Comment: You don't need quotes around any of those in YAML.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenter mentioned, you don't normaly need to place quotes around your front-matter values. I have a *lot* of front-matter in my posts and none of it is quoted.

Hugo expects that date will be a valid date object. By placing quote marks around it you are supplying a string value not a date object. Hugo's .Format fucntion cannot transform that into a valid date because it does not believe you supplied a date, all you gave it was a string of arbitrary characters.